# How do I remove all \r\n from a file, but preserve \n

Tags: csv, replace

I have a CSV with unix line endings, but some of the string values have windows line endings in them:

```
date,notes\n
2014-01-01,"Blah Blah Blah"\n
2014-01-02,"Two things:\r\n  - first thing\r\n  - second thing\n
2014-01-03,"Foo"\n
```

Note that \n and \r just show where the non-printable characters are in the file, it's not how it would look if you opened it in a text editor.

**I want to remove instances of \r\n, but keep the actual line endings, where it's just \n.** The output should look like:

```
date,notes\n
2014-01-01,"Blah Blah Blah"\n
2014-01-02,"Two things:  - first thing  - second thing\n
2014-01-03,"Foo"\n
```

I need something like `tr -d '\r\n' file.csv` but where it deletes the string `\r\n`, rather than either `\r` or `\n`.

If I try to process it with `sed` it's treated like so when processing line-by-line, so it doesn't really work:

```
date,notes
2014-01-01,"Blah Blah Blah"
2014-01-02,"Two things:\r
  - first thing\r
  - second thing
2014-01-03,"Foo"
```

Comment: These are normal CSV files, with quoted strings and within those strings newlines. If you don't want any of the values to have an embedded newlines, parse the CSV properly, then walk over the values and change the ones that need changing, then write out the CSV. Ruby, Python, Perl have excellent libraries for this.

Comment: @Anthon This issue also exists in some deeply nested xml and json files. This is also for exploratory work. I'd prefer to find a tool that does `tr` but on strings.

Comment: That is a naive approach that is not going to work on anything but restricted (i.e. not all real life) files, as your strings can have quotes in them with different escape sequences.

Comment: @Anton It doesn't need to work on all real files, just the files I'm looking at.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether something is in the middle of a string when your example can omit the closing `"` as in your `2004-01-02` line. If between `second thing` and the `\n` in your example there were a `\r`, would you want to preserve it?

Comment: @Mark Edited to clarify my intent. I was trying to emphasize how this is not a simple line ending style swap question, but rather am just trying to remove one style of line ending that happens to be present in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl handles escape sequences, including `\n` for newline, somewhat more comprehensively than older Unix tools.

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n//g'
```

Comment: Why use `perl` to invoke a `sed` command?

Comment: @pfnuesel Sed can be made to work, but it's messier. Since sed doesn't match `\n` on individual lines, you first need to make a loop of `N` commands to concatenate lines together before you can match `\n`.

Comment: I guess I was somewhat misunderstanding the original question, then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\r\\n//g' -i file.csv
```

Comment: That doesn't delete the `\r\n`, just replaces it with `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslashes, i.e.

```
tr -d '\\r\\n' file.csv
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using dos2unix?

Comment: How does that delete the `\r` and the following `\n`

Comment: That's one of the things that program does, converts \r\n to \n

Comment: Which is not the same as deleting them both, which is what the OP asked for.